# Confusion with the use of CupertinoApp and MaterialApp in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I was learning Flutter and came across two types of design MaterialApp and CupertinoApp. So, I wonder if we want to create an app for both android and ios, should we create one separate app with MaterialApp for android and one separate app with CupertinoApp for ios? Or if we, say, create app with only MaterialApp, will ios version of that app automatically get CupertinoApp?

Answer (score 48):

**Material widgets** implements the Material design language for iOS, Android, and web.

**Cupertino widgets** implements the current iOS design language based on Apple's Human Interface Guidelines.

**Why write a Cupertino app?**

> The Material design language was created for any platform, not just Android. When you write a Material app in Flutter, it has the Material look and feel on all devices, even iOS. If you want your app to look like a standard iOS-styled app, then you would use the Cupertino library.
>
> You can technically run a Cupertino app on either Android or iOS, but (due to licensing issues) Cupertino won't have the correct fonts on Android. For this reason, use an iOS-specific device when writing a Cupertino app.
>
> You'll implement a Cupertino style shopping app containing three tabs: one for the product list, one for a product search, and one for the shopping cart.

If you wish to read more on `Cupertino` and `Material`. Check the link below:

[Cupertino and Material](https://medium.com/@sendtosaeed2/flutter-material-cupertino-make-together-a3d2d7849548)

You can also use a flutter package called `flutter_platform_widgets` to check which platform your app is running on and use specific widgets(either Material or Cupertino)

This package link is : [flutter_platform_widgets](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_platform_widgets)

I hope this helps

Comment: so if I want to create app having material design app for android and cupertino design for iPhone then I have to create two separate projects?

Comment: No, you can have one projects for both and use this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_platform_widgets to check for platform you app is running on @SAM

Comment: @void so if not separate projects, I still need to check at every single point when I am adding a widget to see if it is iOS and Android and then add widget accordingly. Don't you think it makes things more complex and hurts the reputation of Flutter being a "Cross-Platform" framework?

Comment: @WaqasYounis not 'every single point' just the parts that you want to adjust the look -and-feel of. So the maybe the top level navigation, dialogs, appbar. Most of the content you can probably keep the same across platforms.

Comment: Why don't we have any sort of AdaptiveApp that automatically uses Material and Cupertino widgets depending on the platform?

Comment: @ArthurKhazbs My assumption (to be taken with salt) is that, due the extra work required to build abstract widgets that can behave differently design-wise per-platform, and due to the fact that design is up to app devs, that the Flutter devs left this piece to devs and the community. They've done quite a bit with allowing one codebase to build to differing platforms let alone differing designs per-platform. But that's where [flutter_platform_widgets](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_platform_widgets) comes in which has abstractions similar to what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 16):

Cross-Platform framework means it can execute in more than one operating system. It doesn't mean it will automatically design your app accordingly, that's up to the developer.
You must check the platform your app is running, you can do that with simple conditions:

```
if(Platform.isIOS){
   return CupertinoButton();
} else if(Platform.IsAndroid) {
    return ElevatedButton();
}
```

Or you can use packages like [flutter_platform_widgets](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_platform_widgets) to help simplify your code.

Comment: Yes, this.
Also, Flutter was designed this way because they saw that most brands try to get the same look-and-feel on all platforms.  https://medium.com/flutter/why-flutter-doesnt-use-oem-widgets-94746e812510
If you want OEM-components you could use other frameworks, like Xamarin (which I don't recommend!).

Comment: You could try Ionic, as it allows you to define platform-agnostic layouts and renders platform-specific components under the hood

Answer (score 2):

And there it comes: the importance of history lessons :)

The Flutter is made by Google. Previously, before they fought for Java, it was a motto: write once and run everywhere (for Java). It was a nice and easy method for Java desktop application to set the UI as the platform:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

But now Java, it isn't a first class citizen for Android.
They invented the Flutter to "write once and run everywhere", just like. Java, but the first class citizen, it isn't the iOS.

I have a code like this:
[image: code]

and it breaks like this:
[image: device]

Ok, is my fault, but I try to achieve what was possible in very easy way with Java: `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`

I would expect all logic to be the same, all function calls and automatically be all Material...whateverWidget the Cupertino...whateverWidget and do not break my code.

These expectations seem irrealistic :)

But when I need to do a lot of platform checking and at the code if-else... and tests those cases too, it is better 2 platform.

So or I use I platform ( branding ) with Material or 2 separate app. Kotlin and Swift.

I can't find the real usage of `CupertinoApp`.

Comment: Agree with it here. It's not just the code issue that can be easily adopt by a simple judge. But whole design (code API) is different between material and cupertino, the ops purpose is same as mine, I don't need whole APP like iOS on Android, but I want at least navibar bottom same, but they can't do that.